# How to handle 'auth/user-not-found' when i run my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, firebase-authentication

I have an array of phone Number which is called phoneNumberArray and i tried to run this function when there is no user present with that number than this error comes i wanted to either reject that number and store in a variable

```
const user = async(acticityObject) => {
  const phoneNumberArray = ['+91555555555','+915585565555'];
  const getAuth = async phoneNumber => {

    return await auth.getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber).catch(console.log);
  };

    const userRecord = await Promise.all(phoneNumberArray.map(getAuth));
return;
}

module.exports = {user}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) you can use ordinary `try/catch`:

```
  const getAuth = async phoneNumber => {

    try {
      return await auth.getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    } catch (err) {
      // Handle, e.g.:
      // console.log(err);
      // if (err === 'auth/user-not-found') { ... }
    }
  };
```